# cmd error "Common was unexpected at this time" to run Spark with Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, cmd

After installing Java in Windows 10, I registered JAVA_HOME variable with value `C:\Java\jdk.1.8.0_301` which is the version I found from running `java -version`. However, the command produces `\Common was unexpected at this time.` I ran `where java` to find other value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe` but it gives the same error. Java was originally installed in Program Files (x86) but I moved out to C:\ after reading that a space in directory might cause an error. After all, I am trying to run Spark after Java is correctly configured.

Comment: Put quotation marks around the whole path…

Comment: Yep, i don’t think it’s a Spark problem at this point, more a Java / Windows issue. If you want to abstract yourself from windows, you can also use docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the installation of Java, relevant information has been written into the windows registry，Moving the installation directory directly will cause the program to be unusable.

It is recommended to uninstall and reinstall in the control panel, and specify a directory without spaces.

Thank you!